# json.net on for loop

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

This is my code, i can't insert my jobject into the jarray. and I don't know if it's best practice.
It's my first time using json and the documentation inside newtonsoft is not very explicit. I would like to create a json like this:

```
{
'-001-':{'value':'index','substring':'0-20'},
'-002-':{'value':'index','substring':'0-5'} 
}
```

and would be formed by:

```
{
row.Cells(0).Value:{'value':row.Cells(1).Value,'substring':row.Cells(2).Value}
}
```

```
Dim json as new JArray
Dim obj as new JObject

For Each row In dtgAssociazione.Rows

    obj =
        New JObject(
             New JProperty(row.Cells(0).Value,
                 New JObject(
                     New JProperty("value", row.Cells(1).Value),
                     New JProperty("substring", row.Cells(2).Value))))


json.add(obj)

Next
```

Once this value has been created I would like to convert it to a string to insert it into a database cell.

Comment: should you be adding the `json` variable to like a list at the end of the for loop?

Comment: @Cal-cium I don't understand what you mean

Comment: well the reason only the last row is getting saved is because each time you loop through the rows, you are overwriting the value in `json` with the current row's value, so you will only ever get the value at the end of the loop. What variable type is `json`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to add the variable `json` to a `List(Of JObject)` or something like that?

Comment: you are absolutely right, sorry but it is the first time that I use json for .net and the documentation inside newtonsoft is really poor. now I edit the whole question to be clearer.